# Apex trigger stuck on 0% test coverage; can't

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I'm blanking on why my trigger is indicating 0% test coverage. I feel like I've treated it like my other triggers, but it is no different than it was when I didn't have a test class at all. Any ideas? Below are pasted the trigger and the test class.

**Trigger**

```
trigger SetOpportunityPreviousDates on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

  // create a set of account ids
  Set<ID> setAccountIDs = new Set<ID>();

  // create set of all close dates
  Set<Date> allCloseDates = new Set<Date>();

  Date closeDate = null;
  Date closeDateWithValue = null;

  // store the close dates for the current opportunity, and check to see if it has a value
  for (Opportunity newOpportunity : Trigger.new) {
    if (newOpportunity.CloseDate != null) {
      closeDate = newOpportunity.CloseDate;
      setAccountIDs.add(newOpportunity.AccountId);
    }
    if (newOpportunity.Contribution_value__c > 0) {
      closeDateWithValue = newOpportunity.CloseDate;
    }
  }

  // get list of accounts with one opportunity for each that is earlier than the current close date
  List<Account> accounts = [Select ID, Name, (Select Id, CloseDate, Contribution_value__c From Opportunities WHERE CloseDate < :closeDate ORDER BY CloseDate DESC LIMIT 1) From Account WHERE ID IN :setAccountIDs];

  // set the most recent date and most recent date with value
  Date mostRecentCloseDate = closeDate;
  Date mostRecentCloseDateWithValue = null;
  if (closeDateWithValue != null) {
    mostRecentCloseDateWithValue = closeDateWithValue;
  }

  // for each account matching our trigger
  for(Account account : accounts) {
    // for each account on the opportunity
    for(Opportunity opportunity : account.Opportunities) {
      //System.debug('the matching closedate is ' + opportunity.CloseDate);
      // set the close date
      mostRecentCloseDate = opportunity.CloseDate;
      if (opportunity.Contribution_value__c > 0) {
        // if the value is > 0, set the close date with value
        mostRecentCloseDateWithValue = opportunity.CloseDate;
      }
    }
  }

  // for each opportunity on trigger, set the date fields if they aren't what they should be
  for (Opportunity opportunity : Trigger.new) {
    if (opportunity.Date_of_previous_opportunity__c != mostRecentCloseDate) {
      opportunity.Date_of_previous_opportunity__c = mostRecentCloseDate;
    }
    if (mostRecentCloseDateWithValue != null && opportunity.Date_of_previous_contribution__c != mostRecentCloseDateWithValue) {
      opportunity.Date_of_previous_contribution__c = mostRecentCloseDateWithValue;
    }
  }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class SetOpportunityPreviousDates_test {

    static void SetOpportunityPreviousDates() {

        // insert some test accounts and contacts
        List<Account> testAccounts = TestDataFactory.createTestAccounts(1, 1, null);

        Id accountId = testAccounts.get(0).Id;

        List<Opportunity> testOpportunities = TestDataFactory.createTestOpportunities(5, accountId);

        List<Opportunity>CountOpportunities = [Select ID from Opportunity];
        System.assertEquals(5,CountOpportunities.size());

        Id campaign = testOpportunities.get(0).CampaignId;

        test.startTest();

        Date today = date.today();
        Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(Name = 'test new campaign', AccountId = accountId, Type = 'Donation', Opportunity_Subtype__c = 'Donation: Individual', Recurrence__c = 'One-time', CampaignId = campaign, Payment_Type__c = 'Check', CloseDate = today + 50, StageName = 'Closed Won', Amount = 25);
        System.debug('insert opportunity '+opportunity);


        // create a set of account ids
        Set<ID> setAccountIDs = new Set<ID>();

        // create set of all close dates
        Set<Date> allCloseDates = new Set<Date>();

        Date closeDate = null;
        Date closeDateWithValue = null;

        // store the close dates for the current opportunity, and check to see if it has a value
        if (opportunity.CloseDate != null) {
            closeDate = opportunity.CloseDate;
            setAccountIDs.add(opportunity.AccountId);
        }
        if (opportunity.Contribution_value__c > 0) {
            closeDateWithValue = opportunity.CloseDate;
        }

        // get list of accounts with one opportunity for each that is earlier than the current close date
        List<Account> accounts = [Select ID, Name, (Select Id, CloseDate, Contribution_value__c From Opportunities WHERE CloseDate < :closeDate ORDER BY CloseDate DESC LIMIT 1) From Account WHERE ID IN :setAccountIDs];

        // set the most recent date and most recent date with value
        Date mostRecentCloseDate = closeDate;
        Date mostRecentCloseDateWithValue = null;
        if (closeDateWithValue != null) {
            mostRecentCloseDateWithValue = closeDateWithValue;
        }


        // for each account matching our trigger
        for(Account account : accounts) {
            // for each account on the opportunity
            for(Opportunity accountOpportunity : account.Opportunities) {
                System.debug('the matching closedate is ' + opportunity.CloseDate);
                // set the close date
                mostRecentCloseDate = accountOpportunity.CloseDate;
                if (accountOpportunity.Contribution_value__c > 0) {
                    // if the value is > 0, set the close date with value
                    mostRecentCloseDateWithValue = accountOpportunity.CloseDate;
                }
            }
        }

        // for each opportunity on trigger, set the date fields if they aren't what they should be
        if (opportunity.Date_of_previous_opportunity__c != mostRecentCloseDate) {
            opportunity.Date_of_previous_opportunity__c = mostRecentCloseDate;
        }
        if (mostRecentCloseDateWithValue != null && opportunity.Date_of_previous_contribution__c != mostRecentCloseDateWithValue) {
            opportunity.Date_of_previous_contribution__c = mostRecentCloseDateWithValue;
        }

        insert opportunity;

        test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Comment: Just to eliminate the extremely obvious: did you run the tests from this test class yet? Did they succeed/fail?

Comment: @Peter I did run it, but it said 0/0 test methods passed. Maybe I'm missing something obvious to indicate the methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to write `testmethod`.

```
public static testmethod void SetOpportunityPreviousDates()
{
 // Test Scenarios...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Can't imagine how I missed that, but now it's 100%. Sigh.